# Cannot run odoo 10 in macOS

Tags: javascript, css, odoo-10

I tried to run odoo 10 from macOS so I'm getting this at the top of the page (lessc is installed so please tell me what s wrong? help me !)

```
odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb.assetsbundle: The "--no-js" argument is deprecated, as inline JavaScript is disabled by default. Use "--js" to enable inline JavaScript (not recommended).
    ArgumentError: Error evaluating function `floor`: argument must be a number in - on line 2475, column 18:
    2474 @planner-height: 13px;
    2475 @planner-margin: floor((@odoo-navbar-height - 2 - @planner-height)/2);
    2476 .o_planner_systray {
    
    This error occurred while compiling the bundle 'web.assets_common' containing:
        - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/variables.less
        - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/mixins/vendor-prefixes.less
        - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/mixins/buttons.less
        - /rh_web/static/src/less/variables.less
        - /web/static/src/less/utils.less
        - /web_editor/static/src/less/web_editor.variables.less
        - /web/static/src/less/fonts.less
        - /web/static/src/less/navbar.less
        - /web/static/src/less/mimetypes.less
        - /web/static/src/less/animation.less
        - /web/static/lib/bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/less/bootstrap-datetimepicker.less
        - /web_planner/static/src/less/web_planner_common.less
        - /rh_web/static/src/less/content_blue_style.less
        - /web_tour/static/src/less/tip.less
        - /web_tour/static/src/less/keyframes.less
        - /web_ruihe/static/src/less/fonts.less
        - /web_ruihe/static/src/less/navbar.less
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sudo npm install -g less@3.0.4 less-plugin-clean-css

Comment: Thank you very much. Downgrading lessc did solve my problem.